# realsense d415 with yolov8 trained model

Tags: object-detection, angle, depth, realsense, yolov8

I'm trying to detect object and get the depth using realsense d415 and yolov8 trained model.

**I've already trained yolov8 and I have best.pt file about it.**
So I want to use this best.pt file to put it in the code about connecting realsense d415.
But i cannot find the code.

I'll put some processes what i did.

1. I searched lots of code so that i realized that i can do this if i have best.weights and .cfg files.

> But also i couldn't convert best.pt file to .weights or .cfg.

2. And also there is another code using .pd file. [text](https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/tensorflow-with-intel-realsense-cameras)

> So i had to convert best.pt file to best.pd but it was so difficult.

3. I followed this code: [text](https://movidius.github.io/ncappzoo/apps/realsense_object_distance_detection.html)
   I've done 'building the example'.

> But I haven't done 'running the example'. I didn't work.

4. There is the most probable way. [text](https://hjdevelop.tistory.com/17)
   But it also has a error:

> profile = pipeline.start(config)
> RuntimeError: Couldn't resolve requests
> And still i cannot find how to solve this problem.

I'm using python 3.
I don't want to use anaconda. Because it's difficult to use it with other system. (I'm making a robot)

**Can i get some codes to get the figures of depth and angle with object detection by using realsense d415?
And i'd like to use best.pt file just not converting it.**
Or if i have to convert it, give me the information about how to convert this file.

I'm appreciate about your help.

If i run the code that i get, I can see the object detection with the model i already trained with yolov8 and the figure of depth and angle at the same time by using realsense d415 camera.